# Generate c# object code and assign values to its properties from an xml document

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

We have a xml file generated from a schema and these are shared with us, we need to generate  c# code for from the xml file and set its properties. I can create a parser to do this, but was checking if there are any OOB solutions.

for example

```
<Customer>
 <fname>tom</fname>
 <lname>jerry</lname>
</Customer>
```

to

```
 Customer cust=new Customer();
 fname="tom";
 lname="jerry";
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to use Xslt to create your desired code output.

This generic stylesheet will use the root node name as your class and assign every child node with it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xa;'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/node()[1]">
        <xsl:variable name="classname" select="local-name()" />

        <xsl:value-of select="concat($classname, ' cust=new ', $classname, '();', $newline)"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), '=&quot;', text(), '&quot;;', $newline)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Customer>
    <fname>tom</fname>
    <lname>jerry</lname>
</Customer>
```

will produce the following output

```
Customer cust=new Customer();
fname="tom";
lname="jerry";
```

Comment: May be i was not clear in my questions, i know how to deseralize, but what i want is how to generate the following code from an xml document.

Customer cc=new Customer()
cc.fname="tom"